# Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined

Tags: django

Iam using swwetify on Djnago so
I set all the parameter on settings , but send me this error

Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47WSA.png)

Well I set the css and Js on Main Page.

have to send me the message

Comment: You need to import the library before you can reference it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.